# Removing items from a javascript array while looping over it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two JavaScript array's. For every item in first array, I need to check if that items exists in second array and if does, I should remove that item from second array. I do not want to create another array. At the end of the process I should have second array with the correct values.  With below code  I am not able to get the desired result.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

var childArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 51, 2, 3, 5];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < childArr.length; j++) {
        if (childArr[j] === arr[i]) {
            childArr.splice(childArr[j], 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to create another array? That would be much easier. `var difference = childArr.filter(function(e) { return arr.indexOf(e) === -1; });`

Comment: The length of `childArr` will be decreased by one when you splice it, right? So you should do to `j` what?

Comment: Underscore [`difference`](http://underscorejs.org/#difference) or [`without`](http://underscorejs.org/#without) are designed specifically for this. If underscore is available to you!

Comment: @JLRishe: I know I can do it with another array. Just wanted to check if there is a way without another array.

Comment: @Teemu:  i know why its not working just wanted to showcase what i have tried.

Comment: Don't do a for loop. It could end up in "index out of bound" if you delete elements.

Do a while, and save the lenght. Then when you delete, recalculate the length

Comment: :)) Teemu was actually SUGGESTING something.

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite Please re-read my comment.

Comment: @JosiahHester: I did looked at without() from underscorejs but returns a new array and it does not accept another array as second parameter. I have to pass one value at time or multiple values separated by ,.

Comment: @Teemu: My apologies. I misread.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to create an implementation of "array difference" algorithm, which could be easily rewritten with [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 51, 2, 3, 5].filter(function(c) {
    return [1, 2, 3].indexOf(c) < 0;
}); // [4, 51, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. using indexOf is not a good option as I need to support IE 8. I forgot to mention that in my question.

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite For both [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility) and [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill) methods there are polyfills, that you may apply to support old browsers. Or if you use jQuery use [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) and [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inArray/) methods correspondingly.

Comment: This doesn't meet OP's stated requirement of modifying the original array and not creating a new array. I already demonstrated pretty much this same approach in the comments 3 minutes before you posted this answer.

Comment: @JLRishe Oh, it is good that you also know about it, nothing unique in this approach really. I was thoroughly waiting until someone posts it as an answer. Personally I don't see any requirements about that in the question: the OP's comment states that he knows how to do it *with another array*, which mostly refers to smth like `arr = []; for ... if (...) arr.push(...);`. However, this solution was not good for the OP because of compatibility issues (which obviously can be bypassed). And don't forget that the OP may be wrong with his concerns about new arrays: there is **nothing** bad in it.

Comment: The question text says "I should remove that item from second array. _I do not want to create another array._" (emphasis added) OP may indeed be mistaken with his/her concerns about new arrays, but s/he already knows how to accomplish this by creating a new array and that's not what the question was about.

Comment: @JLRishe I see no evidence of that knowledge, do you? Again, we are here not only to get the answers for the questions but mainly to learn. I would still say that the provided solution does the job perfectly in most cases and there is no need to reinvent the wheel just because "I do not want to create another array" *for whatever reason no one knows* (emphasis added). If the OP knows about this solution and deliberately not using it, he must have mentioned about that in the comments to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because when you *splice* a member from the array, it's length is shorter and the members are moved one lower, so you skip the next member. The simple solution is to iterate over the array being spliced in reverse.

Also, you need to splice `j`, not `childArr[j]`.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

var childArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 51, 2, 3, 5];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = childArr.length; j >=0; j--) {
        if (childArr[j] === arr[i]) {
            childArr.splice(j, 1);
        }
    }
}

console.log(childArr); // [4, 51, 5]
```

A while loop can also be used:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var j = childArr.length;
    while (j--) {
        if (childArr[j] === arr[i]) {
            childArr.splice(j, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got a small typo:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var childArr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 51, 2, 3, 5];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < childArr.length; j++) {
       if (childArr[j] === arr[i]) {
           childArr.splice(j--, 1); // <-- pass index only.
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: If there are repeated values in *childArr* to be removed, the above will skip some and leave them in the array. Try `childArr = [1, 1, 2, 5]`.

Comment: @RobG It should right? Values of `arr` are compare to the full set of values in `childArr`. It is not doing a `break`. Although suitable answers have been provided, your comment has put in my interest. Have I missed something?

Comment: Yes, you missed something. In `[1,1,2,5]`, when the value at index 0 is spliced, the member at index 1 is moved to index 0, index 2 to 1, and so on. The next member visited is at index 1 and has value 2, so the value 1 moved to index 0 remains when it should be removed.

Comment: @RobG Got it. Edited my answer. That's what iterators are for in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?  It's a little lengthy, but it handles the case where you have multiple occurrences of the values to remove.  It also doesn't use indexOf.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

var childArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 51, 2, 3, 5];


for (var i = 0; i < arr.length;) {
    var foundInChildIndex = null;
    for (var j = 0; j < childArr.length; j++) {
        if (childArr[j] === arr[i]) {
            foundInChildIndex = j;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (foundInChildIndex != null) {
        childArr.splice(foundInChildIndex, 1);
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```